# Can I back out changes to my existing eclipse source code from a prior jar file.

Tags: eclipse

The jar was created in eclipse but does not contain source code, only class files.   Essentially I am wondering if Eclipse has a built in decompile feature that I can use to restore source code to an earlier version.

If I need to use a 3rd party decompile tool what is recommended?

Going forward, I will be sure to include source files in the .jar
Thanks in advance for any advice.

I am using eclipse 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Comment: In future it is worth using a source control system such as SVN or GIT just for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the versions you want to go back to are very recent (in the last few days) you may be able to use the Eclipse local history. Right click on a file and select 'Compare With > Local History' to see what Eclipse has.

You can configure how much local history Eclipse keeps in the Preferences in General > Workspace > Local History.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Both answers were helpful, greg's answer perhaps a bit more helpful, as it was a feature of eclipse I did not know about.  I was able to use this feature to restore my source code so that it matches my current jar file.   We do use Clear Case here and perhaps I should get in the habit of doing checkins daily.  Generally , I only use it when deploying between environments.

Answer (score 1):

There are Java de-compiler plugins available, but keep in mind that you are not going to get your original source code back. The de-compiled source will be equivalent to what was originally compiled, but may not be easy to read, especially if the classes were compiled with symbols removed.

Here is one plugin you can try:

http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I have added this plugin to eclipse.  Both answers were helpful, greg's answer perhaps a bit more helpful, as it was a feature of eclipse I did not know about.